# Oracle encryption wallet 12c

Tags: oracle

I exported a database to a transportable tablespace and send the data to a customer.  They received the error: ORA-28365 Wallet is not open.
Do I need to close the wallet before creating the export?  Is there something on the customer's end that they can do to allow them to import this data?

Haven't had this problem with any other customer since switching to 12c in the last 6 months so this is strange to me that this is the only customer having this problem?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Do you use TDE for these tablespaces?

Comment: I'll be honest, I had to research what "TDE" is?  We recently switched from hosting 11g in-house to using Oracle 12c in the Oracle Cloud. I'm guessing TDE was set up from the start and I didn't know anything about it?  From what I read, TDE has no use for us.  All we do is import data into Oracle, customize the data a bit and then spit it back out as Transportable Tablespaces.  I'm guessing I need to turn TDE off?  Thanks for any additional advice!

Comment: TDE is not a feature that you can simply turn on and off with a switch. Your data is encrypted and it can be decrypted with a key. Tablespaces are encrypted by default in Database Cloud Service.

Comment: I'm confused when you say _"Tablespaces are encrypted by default in Database Cloud Service"._  Wouldn't you have to specifiy the encryption when you create the tablespace, something like this:  `CREATE TABLESPACE encrypt_ts
  DATAFILE '$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/encrypt_df.dbf' SIZE 1M
  ENCRYPTION USING 'AES256'
  DEFAULT STORAGE (ENCRYPT);`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/database-dbaas-cloud/csdbi/use-tablespace-encryption-this-service.html   *All new tablespaces that you create in a Database Cloud Service database are encrypted by default.* ... *By default, any new tablespaces created by using the SQL CREATE TABLESPACE command are encrypted with the AES128 encryption algorithm. You do not need to include the USING 'encrypt_algorithm' clause to use the default encryption.*

Answer (score 0):

For TDE:

[Do transportable tablespaces work with TDE tablespace encryption?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/security/tde-faq-093689.html#A14026)

> Yes, but it requires that the wallet containing the master key is
>   copied to the secondary database. If the tablespace is moved and the
>   master key is not available, the secondary database will return an
>   error when the data in the tablespace is accessed.

[How to use TTS With TDE (Doc ID 1674166.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1674166.1)

> ... Only difference when transporting tablespace using TDE is the
>   wallet needs to copied to the target database. ...